# Source Not Available error(Source is available actually)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have created WPF application solution, added a third-party(cloned git repo locally on my machine) library(Class Library output type) project to the solution, added the library project to my solution:
[image]

And then referenced it in WPF Project settings:
[image]

When a library throws an exception, I get this in Visual Studio:
[image]

I can edit the library project, edit the WPF project, compile everything and it will work. But for whatever reason when an exception is thrown I can't debug the library. How do I fix this?

Comment: Check if the library is a) compiled as Debug and b) that debugging symbols are being generated (somewhere in the project settings of the library project)

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it by unchecking Use Managed Compatibility Mode checkbox: https://i.imgur.com/ICNghmU.png . For whatever reason, it was causing this. As soon as I unchecked it, I can debug the library.

Comment: Yeah it is compiled on Debug configuration and debugging symbols are being generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed Source Not Available error fix by unchecking Use Managed Compatibility Mode Checkbox(checked checkbox causes error to appear) in `Tools-Options`, `Debugging-General`:

[image]

If someone reads this and knows why Use Managed Compatibility Mode was checked and why I couldn't debug my library because of it, please tell us. It took me few hours of googling, asking people around, and trial and error, until I found out that it was my options(after I decided to reset them to see if it was them). I didn't change this checkbox by myself, I would have remembered it. It was like that from the start. I only export my options from older versions of Visual Studio(Visual Studio 2015 > 2017 > 2019) to preserve code style and other options I like.